# Formatting PDF table with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I'm attempting to format a section of a PDF table which was created with PHP. I have 2 tasks which I thought would be quite simple, but I can't figure either one out. Inside a table, I have 4 cells which need a grey background color. I thought something like `fill={ {area=cell fillcolor={gray 0.12}} }` would work (as area=table works fine), but I'm mistaken.

My other issues deals with formatting text within a cell. I need to bold just a portion of the text which is in the middle of a string. Looking at how the rest of the document was created, it seems as though I'm only able to bold the entire cell. Is there a way around this? TIA!!!

Comment: Please tell us what tool you're using to create PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on PDFlib, you can specify macros within textflows that allow a vaguely HTML-like markup to modify text on-the-fly within a string. There's an [example here](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/text-output/wrap-text-around-images/) in 'Case 3'